# Find sum, average and biggest number in an array

Tags: java, arrays

Got a school task to find sum, average and biggest number in an array. Both input and analysis must be if loop. This is what I've done but the sum don't work thus the average is wrong also wrong. What can I improve?

```
    double average = 0;
    int biggest = 0;

    int [] arrayx = new int[5];
    Scanner stdIn =  new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayx.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Write an integer: ");
        arrayx[i] = stdIn.nextInt();
        average += arrayx[i] /arrayx.length;

        if(biggest == 0 || arrayx[i] > biggest)
        {   
            biggest = arrayx[i];            
        }   
    }
    System.out.println("Sum is: " + (average*arrayx.length));
    System.out.println("Average is: " + average);
    System.out.println("Biggest number is: " + biggest);
    stdIn.close();
```

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: Probably integer division.

Comment: No error, just wrong number, often 5-10 number above the correct sum

Comment: @Znarvi my answer assumes integer division, which would actually give you a "smaller" sum than expected, but you're seeing larger sum? are there negative numbers in this input?

Comment: @ACVM sorry, meant lower sum than expected

Comment: The way you're calculating the average is incorrect.

Comment: @Znarvi, ahh then yes, it's integer division. Look at my answer below.

Comment: The easier way to calculate an average is to add up all the items and then divide the **total** by the number of items. Not to divide each item by the number of items.

Comment: I've actually given Java students this task to solve, back when I was a tutor. It is possible to solve without storing anything in an array. Just keep track of the sum, biggest number and number of inputs while inside the loop and divide the sum by the number of inputs in the end.

Comment: @khelwood that's true, but it's still valid (through the distribution property of multiplication). To the OP, your code could be more efficient by doing the division at the very end, but you'd still have to cast 1 as a double else you'll run into integer division problems (but you'll be at most 1 off). Also you can live without the integer array.

Comment: Rather than calculate the average in the loop, a cleaner solution would be to calculate the total sum in the loop, then perform the average calculation once outside of the loop.

Comment: Alright, thanks for all the responses. I started coding last week so all the feedback is really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is integer division.

In Java when you divide two integers, you get an integer (losing anything past the decimal point).

ie. `10 / 3 = 3`

If you want `10 / 3 = 3.33333` you need to cast one of the ints to double.

So rather than:

`average += arrayx[i] /arrayx.length;`

You want to do

`average += ((double) arrayx[i]) /arrayx.length;`

**Note:**

You can make your solution more efficient by getting rid of the int array (do you care about anything but the largest you've ever seen?) and doing the division at the very end of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that both `arrayx[i]` and `arrayx.length` are integers, a.k.a whole numbers.
Thus, when divided, an integer division is used, which takes the whole part of division result.
For example, `7 / 2` in integer division is `3`.

So you add each time to `avarage` an integer, while you wanted a floating point division.
You can cast one of the numbers to `double` to force a FP division:

```
average += (double)arrayx[i] /arrayx.length;
```

Generally, it's better to calculate the sum as an integer and do the division afterwards:

```
sum += arrayx[i];
...
double average = (double)sum / arrayx.length; // Casting here too for FP division.
```

Actually, you don't need the array at all - you use it's items only in the scope of the loop, when you have them anyway, and you know it's length at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Your check for the biggest value is also incorrect.

If you supply the inputs: `{-3, -2, -1, 0, -100}` to your program.

At the end of your loop biggest will be set equal to `-100`.

Your if statement should be changed to:
`if(i == 0 || arrayx[i] > biggest)`

Where `i` is equal to the number of `int`'s that have already been processed.